# Use sass autoprefixer with Roots Toolkit

Tags: sass, roots-toolkit

I just started using roots (roots.cx) and I really love it, but it looks like everything is set up for Stylus and I'm more of a sass user. I have been able to use roots-sass and everything is ok but I need now autoprefixer.

I tried the same set up that is for Stylus:

```
sass:
    use: [axis(), rupture(), autoprefixer()]
    sourcemap: true
```

But is not working, I checked accords documentation/scss and there is no much talk about sass and its options... if there is any...

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- `npm install postcss --save`
- `npm install autoprefixer --save`

Then rename `master.scss` to `master.css.scss` and add the following to `app.coffee`:

```
autoprefixer = require 'autoprefixer'

module.exports =

  postcss:
    use: [
      autoprefixer
    ]
```

Here is a [sample repository](https://github.com/tkraak/roots-sass).

Let us know if you have further questions.